# How to Use Guava MultiMap to store duplicate values against same key and retrieve keys and values

Tags: java, guava, multimap

### This is what I tried

I want keys and values of HashMap....

Help me to iterate through this **MultiMap** and get the keys and values of **HashMap**

```
Multimap<String, HashMap> _multiMap= ArrayListMultimap.create();
Collection col = _multiMap.get(key);

Iterator<HashMap> iterator = col.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String _key = (String) iterator.next().get(key);
    String _value = (String) iterator.next().get(value);
}
```

But it's throwing some error i.e,

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException 
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:862) 
at com.google.common.collect.AbstractMapBasedMultimap$Wrapped 
Collection$Wrapped Iterator.next(AbstractMapBasedMultimap.java:486)
```

Comment: You're calling `iterator.next()` _twice_ for every call to `hasNext()`, you're not calling `hasNext()` and `next()` on the _same_ iterator, and you're using raw types everywhere.  All of those are bugs.

Comment: What is `dbMap`?  You call `hasNext()` on `dbMap.iterator()` and then you use `iterator` of some collection retrieved from the multiMap.  What are `key` and `value` variables?

Comment: You're also getting a _new_ `dbMap.iterator()` every time through the while loop, which resets it to the beginning.

Comment: Hi, @Louis Wassermna .........i.e, typo mistake  i have only iterator.hasNext()

Comment: @SivaReddy that's why you should make a minimal example that shows your example and that works, instead of vaguely copying the code with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer..

```
Multimap<String, HashMap> _multiMap= ArrayListMultimap.create();
Collection col = _multiMap.get(key);

Iterator<HashMap> iterator = col.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    HashMap _hashMap =  iterator.next();
    _hashMap.get(key);
    _hashMap.get(value)
}
```